# Managed Bean для composite component

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Я создал composite component и java класс с аннотациями

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
```

Когда я на тестовой странице создал два моих компонента и попытался загрузить в них разные данные, то понял, что оба компонента работают на одном экземпляре бина.
Я новичок в jsf, подскажите как сделать, чтобы для каждого экземпляра компонента создавался новый экземпляр бина?

Comment: Руководства по составлению композитных компонентов занимают много места. Среди россеянских разработчиков jsf популярностью не пользуется. Поэтому на русском ничего в инете не найти. Но на латинице материала до фига и больше.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался=). Для composite component нужно делать класс с аннотацией `@FacesComponent`. В `.xhtml` файле:

```
<composite:interface
    componentType="myFacesComponent"
      <composite:attribute name="testText" type="java.lang.String" default="Hello World"/>  
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <p:commandButton value="Тест" actionListener="#{cc.test}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.testText}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

В файле `MyFacesComponent.java`:

```
@FacesComponent(value="myFacesComponent")
public class MyFacesComponent extends UINamingContainer {
    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws java.io.IOException {
        String testText= (String)getAttributes().get("testText");
        setTestText(testText);
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    public void test(){
         setTestText("Clicked");
    }

    public String getTestText() { return (String) getStateHelper().eval("testText", ""); }
    public void setTestText(String testText) { getStateHelper().put("testText", testText); }
}
```

Метод `encodeBegin` вызывается при создании компонента. Также есть метод `encodeEnd`. С помощью метода `getAttributes()` можно получить атрибуты нашего компонента. С помощью `StateHelper` можно хранить данные, т.к. поля нашего класса очищаются при каждом новом запросе к серверу.